# Commit data when PopupScreen closed

Tags: blackberry, popup, contacts

I'm still working on BB. I was managed to show Contact List and then select a contact item from it. I implement this on a MainScreen. Below is my code:

```
list = (BlackBerryContactList) PIM.getInstance()
                        .openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
                PIMItem contact = list.choose();
                if (contact != null) {
                    Vector numbers = new Vector();
                    for (int i = 0; i < contact.countValues(Contact.TEL); i++) {
                        selectedMobileNumber = contact.getString(
                                Contact.TEL, i);
                        numbers.addElement(selectedMobileNumber);
                    }
                    ListPopupScreen listPopupScreen = new ListPopupScreen(
                            FormScreen.this, numbers);
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                            listPopupScreen);
                    System.out.println("OKEEEEEE " + selectedMobileNumber);
                }
```

Sometimes a contact item has more than one phone numbers so that i have to show an overriden SopupScreen to list all phone numbers. The question is how to commit data i have selected from so called `ListPopupScreen` so that the number would be shown on a MainScreen i use?

Comment: Implementation of `ListPopupScreen` needs to be modified to support the feature. So, you need to share the code of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't quite enough code in v1 of this question to give a definitive answer.
The screen that is executing this code sample is going to stay on the display stack.  When the popup is dismissed, the screen that pushed the popup will get an [`onExposed()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onExposed%28%29) event.  The popup itself will also get a [`onUiEngineAttached(boolean)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onUiEngineAttached%28boolean%29) event with argument `false` to indicate the popup screen has been detached from the display stack.

Since both events get called for the same action in the UI, the decision to place your "commit" logic in one or the other depends on which one should own the commit process.  I would guess the right choice is the screen that is pushing the PopupScreen, but I can imagine cases where it would make more sense for the PopupScreen to do your "commit" process.

Also note that [`onExposed()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onExposed%28%29) can be called for other reasons that just this specific PopupScreen being dismissed, so make sure your code expects that.